# How to customize the scripts in ionic-angular package.json

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I have created script in my package.json like below and also created particular webpack.config.js file. but when I serve or build on such file then it is serving on default webpack.config not on the custom webpack which is **webpack.myapk.config.js** I need to serve on myapk command with its config.

```
"scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
        "serve:myapk": "ionic-app-scripts serve -w ./config/webpack.myapk.config.js"
    },
```

I have created new custom config file and call tried to call it using ionic serve but is only serving on development and not in myapk.

but when I replace **"ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"** with **"ionic-app-scripts serve -w ./config/webpack.myapk.config.js"** then it is calling that particular webpack and working as expected but I want both command to be used for different environments